# ParserError: Expected ';' but got identifier Error HH600: Compilation failed - getting this error, one step before deploying the contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, openzeppelin, hardhat, binance-smart-chain

I keep getting this error; I was told before to use "const License one in my code, but I don't know which contract I will put it into. Here's the picture: Could someone advise me on what I should do to fix this issue. Would really appreciate it, will build a youtube channel soon to fix common problems.

[image]
[image]
[image]
ParserError: Expected ';' but got identifier
--> contracts/Nikola.sol:5:24:
|
5 |  const License = await ethers.getContractFactory('License');
|                        ^^^^^^

Error HH600: Compilation failed

Answer (score 0):

there is something wrong with your deployment script and/or your hardhat config. as this error isn't reproducible.

suggestion:

if you start a new project with `npx hardhat` and pick `create a basic project`, and copy your solidity contract into it (making sure to change `Greeter` to `Nikola` in the hh.config and deployment scripts, you should be good to go.